# How to change the link for create an account option in login module of Joomla?

Tags: joomla

I want to be able to redirect to my own sign up page when user clicks create an account in joomlas login module.can I achieve this functionality or how do I create my own login form, I'm new to Joomla be descriptive

Answer (score 1):

The best way is using the template override method, when Joomla! render a component or a module first looks in the active template inside the html/ folder, if there is a copy of the extension, joomla use it instead the original. This is always the best choice to not hack the core files.

First look for a html folder in your active template, if not exists create it via ftp, inside create a subfolder mod_login. Upload a copy of modules/mod_login/tmpl/default.php inside the directory created before.

If your version of Joomla! is 3.x change the link in line 101 when says

```
<a href="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_users&view=registration&Itemid=' . UsersHelperRoute::getRegistrationRoute()); ?>">
```

That's the trick!